# How to convert Int to Date format on Grails?

Tags: groovy

How can I convert an integer (40000) into date format?. In excel can be done by changing the format of the cell from number to date.
In that case 40000 = 06/07/2009, the integer is the number of days since 1/1/1900

Is there a function that does this on Grails?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Date addDaysToDate(int noOfDays, Date initDate = null) {
    // If init date provided, add date to it otherwise 
    // consider epoch (1/1/1970 GMT) as init date
    ( ( initDate ?: new Date(0) ) + noOfDays ).clearTime()
}

println addDaysToDate( 40000, Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "1/1/1900") )
println addDaysToDate( 40000 )
```

Comment: If you are in a time zone to the west of Greenwich (negative offset), doesn't the `addDaysToDate(N)` give you a timeless `Date` that is `N-1` days after the epoch date? Here is my reasoning. Consider `addDaysToDate(0)`. After adding zero to the GMT epoch start, all of those negative hour offset time zones still register the calendar date-time as some short while before midnight on `12/31/1969`. Thus when you `clearTime()`, it rolls the clock back even further, to midnight local time at the start of calendar day `12/31/1969`, a full day before Guy Lombardo and the band play *Auld Lang Syne*.

Comment: @BalRog In that case you can directly use epoch date as `Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "1/1/1970")`

Comment: @dmahaptro, I agree that this will solve the immediate problem but there is a deeper problem here. `Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy", "1/1/1970")` is not "The Epoch" for most people. That expression is time zone dependent, but the Epoch is not. If the answer is going to reference local time, then it is perhaps best to avoid the Epoch as a default starting point altogether.